# Footnote inside stackrel

Tags: footnotes, stacking-symbols

I am writing an equation and I'd like to put above the equal sign $(=)$ a footnote describing shortly the reason for that equality.

I tried

```
\[x^2\stackrel{\footnote{foo}}{=}x\ast x\]
```

but this only shows the footnote's number above the equal sign but no `foo` on the bottom of the page.

Any idea? What is the best way to do this kind of trick?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\footnotemark` inside and `\footnotetext` outside.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}      
  \[
   x^2\stackrel{\footnotemark}{=}x\ast x
  \]
  \footnotetext{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Should I use `\footnotesize\footnotemark` to get the same size as the normal `\footnote` command? I tried but it looks like no effect.

Comment: @Sigur: You don't have to worry about the size. It is automatically taken care of. I mean they are same as if you use `\footnote`.

Comment: Hum, I discovered the problem. With `amsart` class we have different sizes for the numbers. With `article` class, everything is OK. Please, try with `amsart`. `test\footnote{bla} $\stackrel{\footnotemark}{=}$\footnotetext{foo} $\stackrel{\footnotesize\footnotemark}{=}$\footnotetext{fookjkj}`

Comment: @Sigur: I don't know much about the internals of `amsart` as I don't use it much. This looks like a potential candidate for a fresh question.

Comment: ok, I'll let the question open for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's really a good idea; the strange number, coming from nowhere, above the equals symbol will hardly be interpreted as a footnote marker.

Footnote markers in math formulas should be avoided because they can get confused with exponents. Why not simply add the explanation beside the formula?

```
\[
x^2 = x * x \qquad\text{(by definition)}
\]
```

(recall that `\text` requires `amsmath`). If the explanation is too long it can go after the formula or, if you *really* prefer footnotes, the footnote marker can be added in the "short explanation".

Comment: I have more than one explanation to write on the same expression. So I guess that putting numbers above the equal signs is the best solution for the moment.