# Footnote in stackrel positioned too high

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

In my document, I'm using symbols for footnotes (*, †, ‡, etc.). However, when I place a footnote mark inside stackrel using `\stackrel{\footnotemark}{=}` for example, the symbol is positioned too high.

[image]

The left is how I would want it to be, like `\stackrel{*}{=}`, the right is how it is. Here's the code for this example (I omitted `\footnotetext`, it's not relevant):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
$\stackrel{*}{=} \;\stackrel{\footnotemark}{=}$
\end{document}
```

How can I let footnote marks in stackrel be positioned lower?

Note: I got the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82306/23992.

Comment: the footnote mark is in superscript position, seems like you want `\textasteriskcentered` or actually since you are in math mode `*`

Comment: is the `*` really meant to indicate a footnote?  it won't be interpreted that way if it's above an `=` -- it will be assumed that this is just a different variation on equals.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, naturally. However, if I use `*`, it doesn't work if I put another footnote before (because then it should change to a dagger).

Comment: @barbarabeeton okay, you've got a point. But then what's the standard way to add a footnote to an equation? In the footnote, I want to put something like "here we use ...".

Comment: Oh OK so you want `\thefootnote` so you just get the current symbol, not `\footnotemark` which makes a raised version of it.

Comment: The standard way is not to put footnote marks in equations. a `*` over an `=` is going to look like a modified math equivalence operator not an `=` with a textual footnote.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hm, yeah, that works normally, but not when I redefine `\thefootnote` as `\fnsymbol{footnote}` (which was suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82306/23992)).

Comment: @CamilStaps -- in egreg's answer to the question you cited, he gives a couple of suggestions.  the particular problem you face with the combination of `=` and `*` is that this is a symbol recognized by unicode, so it's almost impossible to believe that anyone would interpret it differently.

Comment: You could use `\text{\thesymbol}` but don't do this, it won't be readable as an equality.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Okay, fair enough, I'll add some text after the equation. What shall I do with the question? Delete? Or does either of you want to write an answer?

Comment: i don't think deleting this is the best approach.  @DavidCarlisle can give a cogent answer saying why it's a bad idea (he's more of a mathematician than i am, and understands what it all means; i only understand what it should look like to be understood).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Okay, thank you! I'll wait for the answer :)

Comment: Hey I thought @barbarabeeton was going to answer:-) OK, I'll do it...

Comment: You are *such* gentlemen :)

Comment: @CamilStaps I've known barbara a long time. _I _always_ do what she says:-) (well sometimes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\footnotemark` makes a raised marker (by default) as that's the normal convention. If you just want the symbol you can use `\thefootnote` or, in math `\text{\thefootnote}` so that you locally get out of math mode. (`\text` is defined in `amsmath`).

The fact that footnotes by default do not work in math is a hint that you shouldn't be doing this. An = with a * on top is a not uncommon operator: it is a single character in Unicode, U+225B (≛) and accessable as `\starequal` in `unicode-math` or `stix` and perhaps other packages. Readers (including this reader when I read your question) will assume that this is intended to be some mathematical equivalence operator, not a standard = with a textual footnote.